# Pandas how to flatten columns after agg function?

Tags: python, pandas

say I have a df:

```
data=[('a', 1), ('a', 1),('b', 1),('a', 3),('b', 2),('c', 1),('a', 2),('b', 3),('a', 2)]
df=df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['project', 'duration'])

# Then I made an aggregation:
df_agg=df.groupby('project').agg({'duration': ['median', 'mean']}).reset_index()

Out[11]: 
  project duration     
            median mean
0       a        2  1.8
1       b        2  2.0
2       c        1  1.0


In [12]: df_agg.info()                                                                                                                                                    
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
(project, )           3 non-null object
(duration, median)    3 non-null int64
(duration, mean)      3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

However, the `df_agg` is not like an ordinary DataFrame, because the columns look like
a tuple `(duration, median)`, so that I can't get the columns conveniently with `df[['median', 'mean']]`

My question is how can I change the `df_agg` to an ordinary DataFrame, with the columns flattened?

Comment: you have a multi index, you can flatten in by using `droplevel` i.e `df_agg.droplevel(0,axis=1)` but you'll need to rename your columns

Comment: If only performing simple agg on a single column, restructure to: `df.groupby('project')['duration'].agg(['median', 'mean']).reset_index()`

Comment: Of if complex aggregations, you could do something like `df_agg.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df_agg.columns]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `df_agg` dataframe has a MultiIndex for its columns. Only this has to be flattened.

A trivial way is to convert it to a list and `join` each element:

```
df_agg.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df_agg.columns]
```

it gives:

```
  project_  duration_median  duration_mean
0        a                2            1.8
1        b                2            2.0
2        c                1            1.0
```

If you want you can then rename the columns to have nicer names

Comment: To rename arbitrarily: `df_agg.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']`

Comment: What a neat trick! Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: To rename without modifying in place:

`df_agg.pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(["_".join(col) for col in d.columns], axis="columns"))`

Answer (score 2):

you could perform the aggregation on the selected column for the groupby:

```
df.groupby('project')['duration'].agg(['median', 'mean']).add_prefix('duration_').reset_index()
```

- Thank you Chris A for the add_prefix before reset_index idea

output:

```
    project duration_median duration_mean
0   a       2               1.8
1   b       2               2.0
2   c       1               1.0
```

Comment: Instead of `.rename(...)`, you could use `.add_prefix('duration_')` here

Comment: Hi Chris, problem is that if we use that we would also get duration_project, but in general its a great idea!

Comment: Fair point! Could switch round the chaining to do `reset_index` last in that case